# Jest Return undefined snapshot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

I am writing my first jest testing file and got some doubts and errors.

I have created a headers.test.js as my test file. I ran the command and got the output in terminal as passed.  The snapshots file has been generated. But inside that I am getting as

```
exports[`renders correctly 1`] = `undefined`;
```

My header.test.js is like this

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

const headerText = "RK BoilerPlate";

it ("renders correctly", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Header headerText={headerText} />
    );

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Header.js // Component

```
import React from "react"; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./header.css";

const Header = (props) => ({
    handleAuthor() {
        props.history.push("/About");
    },
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="header">
                <h1 onClick={this.handleAuthor.bind(this)}>
                    {this.props.headerText}
                </h1>
            </div>
        );
    } 
});

export default Header;
```

I don't know why its returning undefined in the snapshot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to refactor your `Header` component to

```
import React from "react"; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./header.css";

const Header = (props) => (
  <div className="header">
    <h1 onClick = {() => props.history.push("/About")}>
      {this.props.headerText}
    </h1>
  </div>
);

export default Header;
```

Also it might be good to add a `prop-types` check to the component

Comment: Hey, it worked Thanks, But could you please tell me, what was the mistake that I have written there

Comment: technically I'm not sure if your Header code would work, the `const Header` should return one single component in best practice, but yours is returning an object instead. The way you have written it I'm thinking you want to use class and extend the component like `class Welcome extends React.Component {` (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components.). By using a class, you can define the event handler `handleAuthor() {
        props.history.push("/About");
    }` easily and straight forward. :-)